# CuBlas Matrix Addition using axpy

Tags: aleagpu

I'm trying to do matrix addition using Alea CuBlas axpy, but it seems to only add the top row

```
let matrixAddition (a:float[,]) (b: float[,]) =
     use mA = gpu.AllocateDevice(a)
     use mB = gpu.AllocateDevice(b)
     blas.Axpy(a.Length,1.,mA.Ptr,1,mB.Ptr,1)
     Gpu.Copy2DToHost(mB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one important difference between JokingBear's code and redb's code.

At this line of the problematic code

```
blas.Axpy(a.Length,1.,mA.Ptr,1,mB.Ptr,1)
```

**a** has type **float[,]** and the Length will be the number of elements in that matrix **a**.

However, the corrected code use this

```
blas.Axpy(deviceA.Length, 1f, deviceA.Ptr, 1, deviceB.Ptr, 1);
```

**deviceA** is not **float[,]** anymore but **DeviceMemory2D** object.

The **DeviceMemory2D.Length** is surprisingly larger (384 for 3x3 matrix on my hardware) than **(float[,]).Length** as the allocation on the GPU seems to occupy much more space for some unknown reasons.

The key reason that the JokingBear's code sums only the top row because the **(float[,]).Length** is too short for the data structure on GPU memory which is much longer. There is nothing to do with the version of alea.

Answer (score 1):

I took your example and it runs fine.

Code:

```
        var gpu = Gpu.Default;
        var blas = Blas.Get(Gpu.Default);

        var hostA = new float[,]
        {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9},
        };

        var hostB = new float[,]
        {
            {10, 20, 30},
            {40, 50, 60},
            {70, 80, 90},
        };

        PrintArray(hostA);
        PrintArray(hostB);

        var deviceA = gpu.AllocateDevice(hostA);
        var deviceB = gpu.AllocateDevice(hostB);

        blas.Axpy(deviceA.Length, 1f, deviceA.Ptr, 1, deviceB.Ptr, 1);

        var hostC = Gpu.Copy2DToHost(deviceB);

        PrintArray(hostC);
```

Print Helper:

```
    private static void PrintArray(float[,] array)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (var k = 0; k < array.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", array[i, k]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 10));
    }
```

This is what I get:

[image: output]

Two questions:
 - What version of AleaGpu are you using?
 - What version of the CUDA Toolkit are you using?

I coded my sample against: **Alea 3.0.4-beta2** and I have **CudaToolkit 8.0**.

Just to be sure I tried to code your example in F#.
(I'm not fluent in F#)

Code:

```
let gpu = Gpu.Default;
let blas = Blas.Get(Gpu.Default);

let hostA: float[,] = array2D [[  1.0;  2.0;  3.0 ]; [  4.0;  5.0;  6.0 ]; [  7.0;  8.0;  9.0 ]]
let hostB: float[,] = array2D [[ 10.0; 20.0; 30.0 ]; [ 40.0; 50.0; 60.0 ]; [ 70.0; 80.0; 90.0 ]]

PrintArray(hostA)
PrintArray(hostB)

use deviceA = gpu.AllocateDevice(hostA);
use deviceB = gpu.AllocateDevice(hostB);

blas.Axpy(deviceA.Length, 1.0, deviceA.Ptr, 1, deviceB.Ptr, 1);

let hostC = Gpu.Copy2DToHost(deviceB);

PrintArray(hostC)
```

Print Helper:

```
let PrintArray(array: float[,]): unit =
    for i in 0 .. array.GetLength(0) - 1 do
        for k in 0 .. array.GetLength(1) - 1 do
            Console.Write("{0} ", array.[i, k]);
        Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 10));
```

Comment: I'm using alea 3.0.3 and cuda toolkit 8.0

Comment: Can you try updating to the latest version?
If that doesn't work can you post an example with actual "numeric" data so that I can test it myself?